# Требуется ли запятая, если есть "и"?

Tags: запятые, союзы

Нас окружили, и всех наших либо убили, либо посадили. Нужна ли запятая до союза "и"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Нас окружили и всех наших либо убили, либо посадили.*

Правило таково:

> В односоставных предложениях однородного состава (смысловая и
>   грамматическая однородность!) простые предложения как бы
>   приравниваются к однородным членам, и запятая между ними при наличии
>   одиночных союзов И, ДА, ИЛИ, ЛИБО не ставится:
>
> 1. Неопределённо-личные: Меня допросили и сразу отпустили. Обижают меня да гонят отовсюду вон.
> 2. Безличные: Прохладно и сумрачно.
> 3. Назывные: Ночь, лес да снег.
> 4. Определенно-личные:Идешь по лесу и слушаешь пение птиц.

https://lektsii.org/14-2321.html